# Why can't I join mincraft to the other one on 0.11.1

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can't join my iPod to my iPad with the latest version of mcpe I was wondering if The message came up to you :logged in at at her location ?

Comment: Ops I ment at other location

Comment: Are you using the same account for both?  Sounds like it won't allow that.